# bxslider with responsive background image

Tags: jquery, bxslider, window-resize

I have a bxslider that is a HUGE banner essentially across the top - the content is 'html' and the background image is changed (it is set to cover) using media queries - this is all well and good but I had an issue that on resize it kept generating additional wrappers and the image widths were looking messed up so I figured I would use the destroySlider function and just 'recreate' the slider on resize .... like so

```
var bannerSlider;
var bannerSlider_Config = {
    mode: 'fade',
    preloadImages: 'all',
    auto: true,
    slideMargin: 0
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    bannerSlider = $('#bxslider').bxSlider(bannerSlider_Config);
});

$(window).resize(function () {
   if (bannerSlider) {
        $(bannerSlider).destroySlider();
    }

    bannerSlider = $('#bxslider').bxSlider(bannerSlider_Config);
});
```

My issue is that I am getting a javascript error on resize that says - destroySlider is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

bxslider handles browser resize quite well. I don't think you need to do reinvent the wheel, unless you want to do something different. 
Looks like you called destroySlider for the wrong object. 
Try **bannerSlider.destroySlider();** in place of $(bannerSlider).destroySlider();

```
$(window).resize(function () {
 if (bannerSlider) {
    bannerSlider.destroySlider();
 }

bannerSlider = $('#bxslider').bxSlider(bannerSlider_Config);
});
```